# Show these matrix are similar in a simple way

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you prove these two matrix are similar ? In a very simple way, not using characteristic and minimal polynomials.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$$ $$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\3&-7&5\end{pmatrix}$$

They already have one column in common. I don't really see what are the operations on the two others basis vectors to go from one basis to the other. 
Thank you

Comment: Anyway, having the same characteristic polynomial does not mean the matrices are similar.

Comment: Same  characteristic polynomial + Same minimal polynomial ( dimension = 3 )

Comment: It's more complex than that in the general case.

Comment: Of course, if they're both diagonalisable, withe same eigenvalues (counting multiplicities, they're similar. It becomes more complex when they're not diagonalisable.

Comment: 'They already have one column in common' : I mean we can suppose the tird vector of the first basis is equal to the fist vector of the second basis

Comment: Why it is sufficient in dimension 3 to have same characteristic and minimal polynomials ?

Comment: That is because of the *Jordan normal form*:  matrices are similar (over $\mathbf C$)  to their Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(b1,b2,b3)$ is the first basis. For the second one we take $(e1,e2,e3)$ with $ e1 = b3 $; $e2 = b1 - 7/3 *b3$ ; $e3 = b2 - b1 +5/3 * b3 $ (this is a basis).